# How to compare input and Document in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I Register [ input Email / password to DB ] success. Then, I want to login. If input[email/pass] == document in collection >> go to next page, else console.log['wrong email/pass']

I try to wirte IF/else code but I don't know check condition.

This code is Register form

```
app.post('/register',function(req,res){
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  let dbo = db.db("project");
  let myobj = { Email: req.body.email, Password: req.body.psw } ;

  dbo.collection("Register").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(" document inserted");
    db.close();
  });
});

});
```

This code is Login form

```
app.post('/index',function(req,res){

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  let dbo = db.db("project");

  let cursor = dbo.collection('Register').find();
   cursor.each(function(err,doc) {
    if (doc == req.body.email && req.body.psw){
      console.log("goto next page");

    }
    else{
      console.log('wrong');
    }

   });
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Correct input and wrong input Output is = Wrong

Pls insert loop check all of array pls.

```
app.post('/index',function(req,res){

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("project");

  dbo.collection("Register").findOne({}, function(err, result) {

    if (result.Email == req.body.email && result.Password == req.body.psw) {
      console.log("OK");
    }
    else{
      console.log(result.Email && result.Password);
    }
    db.close();
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to compare individual values, like so:

```
if (doc.Email == req.body.email &&  doc.Password == req.body.psw){
  console.log("goto next page");

}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Email' of null 

How can i fix sir

Comment: Can you share the values of doc and cursor?

Comment: In my DB right? IDK what you want sir. If in DB all values is String

Comment: In the second code snippet in your question, can you share what is the value of coming from database for cursor and doc?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should check for valid request body and the you should do a `fineone` query instead of running a `for-loop` and checking. see the corrected one below :

```js
app.post("/index", function(req, res) {
  let {
    email,
    psw
  } = req.body;
  if (email && psw) {
    console.log("wrong credentials");
    return;
  } else {
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      let dbo = db.db("project");
      let data = dbo.collection("Register").findOne({
        Email: email,
        Password: psw
      });
      if (data) {
        console.log("goto next page");
      } else {
        console.log("wrong");
      }
      db.close();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Sry but It's not working. Now i can check authen with this code but It only check 1value on top of array can you add for loop in code pls. code is on the last in my question

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but I just found a solution to a similar problem and wanted to share.

If you have input values in javascript and want to use them in a mongodb query you need to make them in to strings.

Assuming `user._id` is a value coming from a javascript function call.

This will work:

`{ userId: { $eq:` ${user._id} `} }` ✅

This won't work:

`{ userId: { $eq: user._id } }` ❌